# Routing localhost database to another iP

Tags: mysql, routes, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm working EC2 instances and RDS for my MySQL databases.

I'm wanting to have all scripting refer to localhost for the MySQL Database connection, and then route 3306 I would assume, through to a specific RDS DNS host address. How is this possible?

The reason I'm doing it is because there's no load balancing for RDS yet, and I want to just have a central place for controlling which RDS host is on.

Is this something for iptables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the important thing is that you want to create an alias for your database server so that you can change the IP address later without having to change any of your code. For that purpose, you can use the `/etc/hosts` file. But if you use this technique, do not use or change the `localhost` setting. `localhost` is special and changing the definition of `localhost` in your /etc/hosts file can have bad side effects.

Instead, create a separate entry in `/etc/hosts` for your database server. The format of the file is IP_ADDRESS NAME. For example:

```
 127.0.0.1 dbserver
```

All of your code can then refer to `dbserver` for the hostname of your database server. Later, you can change the IP address in the `/etc/hosts` file to something else when you move your database.

Comment: Great idea and feedback, thanks. One question, AWS supply public DNS endpoint address rather than IP. I have tried this with the DNS endpoint, but it doesn't seem to work. Is it not possible to do this with DNS?

Comment: Given the scenario explained, would it be better to use a subdomain on a cname link to the DNS on a low TTL?

Comment: From what I understand of RDS, the endpoint should never change so that should work. You could also get the IP of the endpoint and use that... but I don't know how stable they are (how often it might change). Going out over the public internet to access your DB server is going to be slow. It'd be better performance-wise if you could use a private local network IP for the RDS server. But, I don't know if that's possible, or if Amazon does some magic to optimize the routing from EC2 to RDS.

Comment: The endpoint is a DNS hostname rather than IP, because the IPs do change from time to time, and/or they shared boxes between instances in a virtual enviro. Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to be the answer for this specific situation.